# Azure pipelines shows skipped stages

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-devops-extensions

I have below azure pipeline yaml file. I have tried the below setup which runs the test stage , but its also shows me the build & deploy stages, which I don't want.

```
variables:
  vmImageName: "ubuntu-latest"

trigger:
  - production

stages:
  - stage: Test
    displayName: Test stage
    condition: eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'IndividualCI')
    jobs:
      - job: Test
        displayName: Test job
        pool:
          vmImage: $(vmImageName)
        steps:
          - script: |
              echo "Testing ..."
            displayName: 'Test job script'

  - stage: Build
    displayName: Build stage
    condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/production'), ne(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest'))
    jobs:
.............SAME AS ABOVE ..........
          - script: |
              echo "Building ..."
            displayName: 'Build job script'

  - stage: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy to Dev
    dependsOn: Build
    condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/production'), ne(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest'))
.............SAME AS ABOVE ..........
        steps:
          - script: |
              echo "Deploying ..."
            displayName: 'Deploy job script'
```

In gitlab it's very easy. Gitlab pipelines shows only the stages which is mentioned like only on main or merge_request. I am expecting the same here in azure pipelines.

I am trying in every possible way, But still I could see all the stages in my pipelines.

[image]

I want:

Test -> to be triggered & visible only on commits & PR

Build & Deploy -> Build & Deploy stages only visible on when merged to default branch

What changes should I make in azure pipeline yaml for the same ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`condition` parameters show that the stage (or job, or step) *exist*, but weren't run.

If you want to not have a stage/job/step appear at all, you'll need to use compile-time logic to not even include that structure in the final YAML document in the first place.

i.e.

```
- ${{ if and(eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/production'), ne(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest')) }}:
  - stage: Build
    ...etc...
  - stage: Deploy
    ...etc...
```

Of course, if you do that, you can remove the `condition` as well.

Comment: There is an MS blog that goes into this in detail: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/healthcare-and-life-sciences/azure-devops-pipelines-if-expressions-and-conditions/ba-p/3737159